# Wrapfig: No image after section

Tags: graphics, miktex, wrapfigure

I am trying to figure out why I am getting no image and no error message in the log when using `wrapfigure` environment right after a sectioning command. The only way how I was able to force `wrapfigure` into showing the image was to enter some text between the section heading and the beginning of `wrapfigure` environment — I have therefore got what I wanted by inserting a paragraph consisting of one non-breaking space and removing the resulting blank line by adding a negative `\vspace`, which, I suppose, is not the way how things should work.

For a while I thought I have a similar problem as in [Wrapfigures beneath section headings misbehave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20629), but if I understood it correctly the problem there is caused by a page break, which is not my case.

FWIIW, I am running a recent version of MiKTeX, but I have first came across this problem about a year ago ...

An illustration of the problem:

[image: Illustration of a wrapfigure environment problem.]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
%% Tight margins
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

%% Does not work
\section*{Curricula Vitae}
%% Do not allow the figure to float away ...
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{96pt}
  %% ... but nevertheless this image does not show up.
  \includegraphics[width=96pt,height=22pt]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
\textbf{Primum Author} condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Mauris elementum 
mauris vitae tortor. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Nam quis nulla.

\section*{Working example}
%% Everything is okay if there is a paragraph of text between \section and
%% \begin{wrapfigure}. Adding the following line seems to solve my problem:
~\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
%%
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{96pt}
  \includegraphics[width=96pt,height=22pt]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
\textbf{Primum Author} condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Mauris elementum
mauris vitae tortor. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Nam quis nulla.

\end{document}
```

Any ideas? I have an urgent feeling that I have missed something obvious.

---

**Edit:** The comment of @JohnKormylo caused me to look at the code once again, and after some additional testing I am pretty sure that the `\noindent` is the culprit. While

```
\section{...}
\begin{wrapfigure}...\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
<paragraph text>
```

will not display the contents of the `wrapfigure` environment, moving `\noindent` between `\section` and `\begin{wrapfigure}` seems to work.

Any idea why is this so?

Comment: \leavevmode will also work.  \section does something sneaky to prevent the next line from being indented.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use the plain TeX macro package `insbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
%% Tight margins
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

%% Does not work
\section*{Curricula Vitae}
%
\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[width=96pt,height=22pt]{example-image}}[-1]\noindent
\textbf{Primum Author} condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Mauris elementum
mauris vitae tortor. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Nam quis nulla.

\section*{Working example}
%% Everything is okay if there is a paragraph of text between \section and
%% \begin{wrapfigure}. Adding the following line seems to solve my problem:
~\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
%%
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{96pt}
  \includegraphics[width=96pt,height=22pt]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
\textbf{Primum Author} condimentum augue id magna semper rutrum. Mauris elementum
mauris vitae tortor. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Nam quis nulla.

\end{document}
```

[image]